# How to make my dog walk with me?

Tags: dogs, training

Whenever I when out for a walk with my pet dog *(with the leash on)*, he just forgets about me and tries to run for different things like *(dogs, cats, car)* and it gets harder for me to control him.

I want to take him on a walk, but due to his behaviour, I try to avoid talking him for a walk.

Can someone tell me how to get this correct?

**Dog:** Labrador

**Age:** 1 and half year

**Gender:** Male

Comment: When did this behavior start?

Comment: When he was strong enough to pull me

Comment: All dogs pull on the lead.  You need to prevent that before they get too strong which he likely is now.  We have a 3 month labrador puppy and he's already quite strong but we have now mostly stopped him from pulling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice: take him on walks *more often*, many times per week and you may find that your dog becomes much more used to the environment, thus needing to pay less attention to all of the triggers around him. Don't let it get you down, like anything with dog obedience, its often the frequent corrections and work that get you the results you want.

---

We have a Labrador Retriever, 1.5 years old. We do not take her on walks as often as we should, we know this very well, but we also live in a climate that rains a **lot**, so it's not always the most fun taking her out on a walk and then having to dry her off (she is an 'inside-dog' for most of the day).

Something I have found to be interesting though, and might be stating the obvious, but the more often we walk her, the less she attempts to run off and/or chase objects. She is a much better/behaved walking buddy when we take her frequently. I've also found that she is a wonderful dog to run with. Running wears her down much faster and then walking afterward becomes easier and she is less interested in other things.

Comment: When taking him on a walk, and he saw something, it's hard to control him, that point of time he completely forgets about me and tries to run after that object or dog or animal.

Comment: @YashuMittal I agree that is a very common thing for dogs to do when they are young and inexperienced with walking. I am just encouraging more walking so that you and him can build an understanding of the expectations before he becomes much older and it is hard to reverse the behavior. He is young now and easier to train.